# I want to hide an element, but document.getElementById() is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a page where a user can add images to his profile. I have three elements.

1. Placeholder for when there isn't an image yet. (uploadbox)
2. Preview of the image selected bij the file-input (preview-img)
3. Preview of the current image already in the database (current-img)

I want to hide or show these elements based on the situation, but when I want to put the ID of the element I want to hide/show in document.getElementById() it is null, but a console.log() of the parameter shows it just fine.

HTML:

```
<div class="pf-field img-field">
  <div class="uploadbox" id = "box1">
    <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
      <i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i> <span>Upload Image</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
    <img id="img1" class="preview-img" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="your image" />
    <img class="current-img" src="{{user:img_1}}" alt="your image" />
  </label>
  <input name="image_1" type="file" title="file-upload1" class="hide" id="file-upload1" onchange="readURL(this, img1, box1);">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function readURL(input, preview, box) {       
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $(preview)
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
      console.log(box); // Output: <div id="box1" class="uploadbox"> fotoimpressie:263:23
      console.log(preview); // Output: <img id="img1" class="preview-img" src="removed for readability" alt="your image"> fotoimpressie:264:23
      document.getElementById(box).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(preview).style.display = "block";
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `getElementById` accepts a *string* as a parameter, not an element. Also, you might consider attaching events properly with Javascript instead of inline attributes (which is as bad as `eval` and hard to manage, as you're experiencing here)

Comment: I added quotes and that works now. How do I attach events properly?

Comment: Look up `addEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

*You Can use this code I tested it.*

```js
function readURL(input, preview, box) {       
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $(preview).attr('src', e.target.result);
          document.getElementById("box1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("img1").style.display = "block";
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="pf-field img-field">
      <div class="uploadbox" id = "box1">
     <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
          <i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i> <span>Upload Image</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
        <img id="img1" class="preview-img" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="your image" />
        <img class="current-img" src="{{user:img_1}}" alt="your image" />
      </label>
      <input name="image_1" type="file" title="file-upload1" class="hide" id="file-upload1" onchange="readURL(this, img1, box1);">
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your parameters and using the function:

```
function readURL(input) {       
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result);
      document.getElementById('box1').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('img1').style.display = "block";
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated above, you are passing in the whole HTML element to the 'getElementById' but that function requires a string with the id of the element not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working.
The difference is that you are trying to get your box1 object using `getElementbyId(box1)` but parameter box1 is already your desired object.

So, I commented your last two lines and added two more lines which handle variables as object variables and not like string variables.

One more thing: Adding single quote will make it static. But when you are forwarding objects as variables then you must utilize them.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="pf-field img-field">
  <div class="uploadbox" id = "box1">
    <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
      <i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i> <span>Upload Image</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <label for="file-upload1" class="custom-file-upload" >
    <img id="img1" class="preview-img" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="your image" />
    <img class="current-img" src="{{user:img_1}}" alt="your image" />
  </label>
  <input name="image_1" type="file" title="file-upload1" class="hide" id="file-upload1" onchange="readURL(this, img1, box1);">
</div>
<script>
function readURL(input, preview, box) {       
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $(preview)
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
      console.log(box); // Output: <div id="box1" class="uploadbox"> fotoimpressie:263:23
      console.log(preview); // Output: <img id="img1" class="preview-img" src="removed for readability" alt="your image"> fotoimpressie:264:23
      //document.getElementById(box).style.display = "none";
      //document.getElementById(preview).style.display = "block";
      box.style.display = "none";
      preview.style.display = "block";
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this;

```
document.getElementById(box.id).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(preview.id).style.display = "block";
```

Or this;

```
box.style.display = "none";
preview.style.display = "block";
```